# IP Whitelisting all Amazon EC2 servers in Region Ireland

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a web service which runs on Elastic Beanstalk, with a dynamic amount of instances, I have an external service that needs to whitelist my IP's, they can whitelist an entire region, where can I find all possible IP's used by amazon in Ireland?

I have tried setting up a NAT gateway, but it seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS publishes its IP address ranges to a json file that is available in their documentation.  You can parse it using the AWS Tools for PowerShell or via the jq tool in linux.

Direct link: https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

### Examples

The following examples filters by all Ipv4 addresses in eu-west-1 (Ireland) for the 'EC2' service, and selects only their IP Prefix.

#### AWS Tools For PowerShell

```
(@(Get-AWSPublicIpAddressRange -Region eu-west-1) | ? { $_.IpAddressFormat -eq 'Ipv4'-and $_.Service -eq 'EC2' }).IpPrefix
```

#### jq

Note: This example assumes you've downloaded the ip-ranges.json and it is in your current directory.

```
jq -r '.prefixes[] | select((.region=="eu-west-1") and .service=="EC2") | .ip_prefix' < ip-ranges.json
```

### IP Address Range Changes

If you intend to use this as a whitelist on your side, make sure you are regularly checking this json and keep up to date with any changes, because you have no guarantee that this list won't change over time.

AWS provides an SNS topic that publishes a message whenever there is IP Address Range Change. You can use this notification as a trigger to automate updates to your whitelist. For example, you could trigger a lambda on SNS publish that runs the example queries above.

SNS topic ARN: `arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged`

More details on how to subscribe [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html#subscribe-notifications).

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - AWS IP Address Ranges](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html#aws-ip-syntax)
- [AWS Documentation - Get-AWSPublicIpAddressRange Cmdlet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-AWSPublicIpAddressRange.html)
- [AWS Developer Blog - Querying the Public IP Address Ranges for AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/querying-the-public-ip-address-ranges-for-aws/)
- [AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/)
- [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer, but there'a a flaw in the question, for sure. According to the resources mentioned here, my math indicates that EC2 in Ireland (eu-west-1) currently controls 3,167,504 IP addresses in 30 netblocks.  It seems *highly* unlikely that any 3rd party provider would consider opening these up in a whitelist to be a reasonable request.  OP needs a static address (EIP), and a NAT Gateway, no two ways about it.